# My Cordova Android App WWW directory is not being updated

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I'm building a cordova android application using eclipse, the index.html file is written in aptana studio 3
the issue is that I have nodified some parts in the html and js files and they are not being updated in the application when I build it (i've tried the emulator and the real device)
any suggestions on how to fix that?
I've tried to:
-clean the project
-rebuild the project
-remove the index.html file and re-add it

nothing worked

Thank you..

Comment: have you deleted the app on the android device, so that a fresh install is made?

Comment: @DennisAnderson Yes, I even deleted the cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you work in the root folder. If you make changes in the root www folder, you won't see changes in eclipse or apk built by eclipse unless you run cordova prepare or cordova build to copy the files from /www/ to /platforms/android/assets/www.

when this is done you run cordova build android or cordova run android (when device is connected)

Answer (score 1):

Your project should look like this:

```
MyApp
   -> www
      -> index.html
   -> platforms
      -> Android
         -> www
         -> other folders
      -> ios
        -> wwww and other folders
   -> other stuff...
```

Once you did your changes in MyApp->www->index.html you should run

```
cordova build android; cordova run --device android;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem

```
cordova prepare
cordova build
```

refreshed project as well nothing worked then i have deleted apk in

```
platforms/android/bin/hellocordova-debug.apk
```

then my changes in index.html and home.html are visible on my device.